# Question on convolution

Tags: convolution, continuous-signals, linear-systems

I am stuck at question number 2.8

[image: I am having a problem in the question number 2.8]

This is how I have gone about solving it:

I have calculated $y(t)$ by convolving $x(t)$ with $h(t)$ using the fact that $x(t)$ convolved with an impulse at $t=t_0$ is just the same signal $x(t)$ time shifted by $t_0$. Hence,

$$y(t)= x(t+2) + 2x(t+1)$$

Now, according to the answer in the book, signal $y(t)$ is $t+3$ on $-2 < t \leq -1$. But, according to my answer, if we add $x(t+2) + 2x(t+1)$, the value of $y(t)$ at $t=-1$ is $4$. Why Please help me.

Also, why is it that in the answer in the book they haven't included $t=-2$ in the range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x(t)=\begin{cases}
 t+1\qquad & 0\leq t\leq1 \\
 2-t\qquad &  1<t \leq2 \\
0\qquad & \mathrm{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

---

$$f_1(t)=x(t+2)=\begin{cases}
 t+2+1\qquad & 0\leq t+2\leq1 \\
 2-(t+2)\qquad &  1<t+2 \leq2 \\
0\qquad & \mathrm{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

$$f_1(t)=x(t+2)=\begin{cases}
 t+3\qquad &-2\leq t\leq-1 \\
 -t\qquad &  -1<t \leq0 \\
0\qquad &\mathrm{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

---

$$f_2(t)=2x(t+1)=\begin{cases}
 2(t+1+1)\qquad & 0\leq t+1\leq1 \\
 2(2-(t+1))\qquad &  1<t+1 \leq2 \\
0\qquad &\mathrm{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

$$f_2(t)=2x(t+1)=\begin{cases}
 2t+4\qquad & -1\leq t\leq0\\
 2-2t\qquad &  0<t \leq1 \\
0\qquad &\mathrm{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

---

Now add them
$$y(t)=x(t+2)+2x(t+1)=\begin{cases}
 t+3\qquad & -2\leq t<-1 \\
3t+7\qquad &t=-1\\
 t+4\qquad &  -1<t \leq0 \\
2-2t\qquad &0<t\leq1\\
0\qquad &\mathrm{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Now check $f_1(-1)=2$,$f_2(-1)=2$,also $y(-1)=f_1(-1)+f_2(-1)=4$

Comment: But isn't the value of x(t+2) and 2x(t+1) both 2 at t=-1. Hence should'nt y(t) be 2+2=4 at t=-1?

Comment: @Rohit I have added a minus sign in the last system, I hope it's consistent

Comment: sir I cannot understand why $0 < t \leq1 $ in the last equation? should it dont be $0\geq t \leq 1$ plz help I'm totally confused?

Comment: @Rohit sir why not sir? Plz help I'm newbei thnx... :-))

Comment: @YOGENDRASINGH Actually you are caculating the value of the signal at the point of discontinuity at the point of dicountinuity its value is undefined...like unit step signal at t=0 its value is undefined.So for x(t+2) we can't exaclty say if its value is 2 or 1 similarly for 2x(t+1) is also a point of discountinuity so Its value can be either 0 or 2 or anyting thatswhy its value is changing y(t) and for separate function.

Comment: @Fat32 LOL....So you are repeating my all words. :-)))...and this $0\geq t \leq 1$ LOL

Comment: Rohit, right the function y(t)  is discontinuous at t=-1. But how can the function x(t+2) take any value at t=-1. Isn't the value of x(t) externally defined at t=1 to be equal to t+1? And similarly shouldn't the value of x(t+2) be externally defined to be equal to t+3 at t=-1?

Comment: @YOGENDRASINGH Oh..I got you...you can include -2 too.. sorry my mistake

Comment: Also, Rohit I am wondering why would the value of y(t) be t+3 on -2<t<=-1. Because if put t=-1 in y(t), it becomes, y(-1)=x(t+2)+2x(t+1)=x(1)+2x(0)=2+2=4. Then why are you saying y(t) will not be defined at t=-1 when both x(1) and x(0) have been defined as per the question.

Comment: @YOGENDRASINGH Now check the update please

Comment: Rohit, but the answer in the book is y(t) = t+3 on -2 < t <= -1.

Comment: Basically, that was my doubt in the question in the first place.

Comment: @YOGENDRASINGH Yes....thats wrong in the book..It was not satisfying the equation earlier as you said..Now its right.if you draw the graph there will not be any confusion you will get the same graph.

Comment: Except that, plotting the graph is still a feat. It will have a strange behaviour at t=-1.

Comment: @YOGENDRASINGH yes at t=-1 it will sudden increase the graph from 2 to 4

Comment: And at( t=-1+) it will rise linearly according to t+4, that is just after t=-1, it will rise linearly from 3 at -1+ to 4 at t=0. Right ?

Comment: @YOGENDRASINGH Yes right

Comment: @YOGENDRA SINGH If your doubt cleared from the answer then you should "accept the answer".

Comment: I did. Sorry Rohit.